# Pandas: Groupby and apply function that returns a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, apply

I have a dataframe. I am grouping it by columns A, B and applying a function to each group. The function returns a dictionary which is appended as a row to a new dataframe. This is what I have done:

```
def foo(x):
   new_row = {}
   #Performs operation on group x
   new_row['A'] = value1
   new_row['B'] = value2
   new_row['C'] = value3
   new_row['D'] = value4
   return new_row #Returns a dictionary



df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["A", "B", "C", "D"])
row = df1.groupby(['A', 'B'], as_index=False).apply(foo)
print(type(row)) #Returns dataframe instead of dictionary
df = df.append(row, ignore_index=True)
```

`df` is having only NaN values after the operation. Is there a more efficient way to perform this?

Comment: Can you show the sample of the dictionary which is returned by `foo`?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma, Please see the edits. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us create a list of records by iterating over the groups of the `groupby` object and apply the function `foo` on each group, then you can `append` these records to the given dataframe

```
df.append([foo(x) for _, x in df.groupby(['A', 'B'])], ignore_index=True)
```

Alternatively we can also use `apply`

```
df.append([*df.groupby('col_1').apply(foo)], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: @Shubam Sharma, Thankyou for getting back! So what value should `foo` return?

Comment: The function `foo` can return a `dictionary` like `new_row`

Comment: Thank you so much! In the answer, because we are grouping by df1, I believe it should be: `df = df.append([foo(x) for _, x in df1.groupby(['A', 'B'])], ignore_index=True)` right?

Comment: Hi, right now my function is returning a list of dictionaries instead of a single dictionary. So how do we modify this efficiently? `df.append([foo(x) for _, x in df.groupby(['A', 'B'])], ignore_index=True)`. Right now, it's like appending a list of list of dictionaries though.

Comment: @Animeartist We need to flatten the nested list of dictionaries. Check `df = df.append(np.hstack([foo(x) for _, x in df1.groupby(['A', 'B'])]), ignore_index=True)` OR `df.append([y for _, x in df1.groupby(['A', 'B']) for y in foo(x)], ignore_index=True)`

Comment: Thank you for getting back but unfortunately it isn't working though. I am getting a dataframe full of NaN values.

Comment: I made few changes in the code and now it's working as expected. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Animeartist Glad it worked for you. happy coding!